# How to build typescript files so I can use them in frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, yarnpkg

I got an `index.ts` file and it basically exports an object and some functions that does some stuff with that object. Below is a minimal example:

```
export const myObject = {a: 1, b: 2}

export function getKeys() {
  return Object.keys(myObject);
}

export function getValues() {
  return Object.values(myObject);
}
```

I want to use `myObject` and the exported functions in a TypeScript React frontend. I built the package with the below configuration into the `dist` folder.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.test.ts"],
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json"
}
```

When I import these functions into the React app `myObject` is `undefined` and I get the below error when I try to use the functions:

```
...WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1.getKeys is not a function
```

My vscode automatically recognizes the functions and imports them.

What am I doing wrong or what is missing?

The way I import:

```
import { myObject, getKeys } from "my-package"
```

Comment: Please show in your question _how_ you are importing this object and the functions.

Comment: I added it to the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const myObject = {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Comment: It is correct in the original files. I made a mistake on the question and now I fixed it.